# is_archive for custom tax archive page?

Tags: conditional-tags

Having trouble getting the achieve page of a custom taxonomy to know its that page.

It just shows the detail from the default is_archive blog page...

This is what i've tried..

```
<?php  } elseif ( is_archive() && is_tax() == 'article-area') { get_template_part( 'includes/inc-article' ) ?>
```

When all its doing is showing the details from this...

```
<?php  } elseif ( is_archive() ) { get_template_part( 'includes/inc-blog' ) ?>
```

Any ideas, as i'm stumped? :(

Thanks for looking.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't it be

is_tax('article-area')